# Rendering OpenGL (instanced?) geometry with world-position determined using an index in the shader

Tags: opengl, geometry, instance, shader, vbo

Trying to keep questions and answers simpler, I will reduce my problem from 3d to 2d.

I have a 2d grid with X*Y cells in 2d space. It is defined simply by X, Y, bBoxMin2d and bBoxMax2d.

On the GPU (currently in a VBO), I have X*Y (unsigned 8 bit) integers, which define the brightness of the cells. So, for X=Y=3, if the VBO contains {4, 7, 3, 2, 9, 4, 7, 2, 1}, the grid should be rendered using patches of the following brightness:

```
4 7 3
2 9 4
7 2 1
```

I know I could create another VBO containing the world-position of the center of each cell and use the geometry shader to create a patch to be passed on to the fragment shader.

However, I want to be more efficient and do without a second VBO. My thinking is that if every instance of the geometry shader had its own thread index (similar to CUDA), it could create the cell's patch using only that index, and bBoxMin2d and bBoxMax2d from e.g. a UBO. The fragment shader would then read the color from the VBO and I'd be happy.

But it seems there is no geometry-shader thread-index. So, how can I solve my problem?

Please don't tell me to use another VBO with the positions - that would increase memory requirements from sizeof(uint8_t) = 1 byte per cell to at least sizeof(float3) + sizeof(uint8_t) = 13 bytes. And I have lots of cells :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, let's deal with the Elephant in the Room. You have a large grid of 3D cells that you're rendering. You're making a Minecraft clone; it's best to be up-front about this.

What you're trying to do will in no way be *efficient*. Using a geometry shader to generate squares/cubes from a single number and `gl_PrimitiveIDIn` is not an efficient way to render a bunch of cubes. The efficient way to do so is to do what Minecraft does: creates buffer object(s) containing the visible terrain and render *that*. This will take up more memory, but you'll be a lot more likely to get reasonable performance out of rendering "lots of cells".

If you want to know how to make your current method work, presumably (I have to presume because you didn't *say*), your GS takes as its [input `points​` and converts this into several `triangle_strip​` outputs](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Geometry_Shader#Primitive_in.2Fout_specification). So each vertex input becomes an output quad/cube.

This is simple to deal with: [use `gl_PrimitiveIDIn`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Geometry_Shader#Primitive_inputs). Because you're taking points as input, the primitive count is the same as the vertex count. So if you have a space of 3x3, and `gl_PrimitiveIDIn` is 4, you know that you're in the (1, 1) part of that space:

```
vec2 spacePos.xy = vec2(mod(gl_PrimitiveIDIn, space.x), (gl_PrimitiveIDIn / space.y));
```

That's the XY index where you are in your abstract space. Note that `space` should be an `ivec2` uniform variable somewhere, which defines the number of indices in X and Y you have. The 3D version is slightly more complex, but also doable.

Once you have your abstract space index, you can compute vertex positions based on that. I'll assume you know how to do that.

Comment: Thanks Nicol, I think gl_PrimitiveIDIn was what I was looking for!1) Why exactly will this not be efficient? 2) If I continue with my inefficient idea, would I have to use sth. like `glVertexAttribPointer(0,1,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,...)` and then `glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, ...)`? You confused me a little with the "GS vertex" input, because the vertex isn't input, but calculated from the UBO values (X,Y,BBOX)

Comment: 3) Could I use a `uint` (4byte?) datatype in the shaders, even though I supply only 1 byte `uint8` data in the VBO? Will OpenGL cast/convert this for me? If not, how can I do this? 4) Will my approach be faster if I create billboard-patches oriented towards the camera in the GS instead of 3d-boxes?

Answer (score 0):

Whether **gl_PrimitiveIDIn** or **gl_InvocationID** in geometry shader help you.[*Requires GLSL 4.0 or ARB_gpu_shader5*]